# why doesn't this function execute the request?

Tags: solidity

i have a loanrequest function and an executeRequest function, but for some reason the execute function does not send the requested ether to the address.

my code below

````
    struct Request {
        uint value;
        address to;
        bytes data;
        bool granted;
    }
    Request[] public requests; // store requests


    function submitLoanRequest(address _to, uint _value, bytes calldata _data)
        external {
        requests.push(Request({
            to: _to,
            value: _value,
            data: _data,
            granted: false
        }));
    }

    function executeLoanRequest(uint _requestId) external
    {
        Request storage request = requests[_requestId];
        request.granted = true;
        require(request.granted, "not granted");
        (bool granted, ) = request.to.call{value: request.value}(
            request.data
        );

        require(granted = true, "request failed");
    } 
}```

is there another way to implement the execute function?
````

Comment: I think this part is wrong:

```
require(granted = true, "request failed");
```

Should be

```
require(granted, "request failed");
```

Comment: thank you for taking your time to go over this linda, but i checked and its not still working. That syntax should work shouldn't it?

Comment: Can you elaborate "how" it now works? e.g. error message, wrong behavior etc

Comment: alright, i simplified the code above so it just has the important stuff, but initially the contract is support to let people contribute and request a loan. the rest of the code works down to the part where it's supposed to send the amount a Benefactor requests a loan of. There's no error message, and all the security measures check. On the remix the transaction is confirmed but the ether never actually gets sent out.